How Resend OTP CountDown Timer in Livewire 3 and Alpine Js
I want to make OTP resend the countdown. anyone can you help me
we try Livewire and Alpine to make OTP resend functionality
 $data = $this->sendSMS($this->phone_number, $otp);
        
         if ($data === true) {
             $this->isOtpGenerated = true;
         } else {
             $this->addError('phone_number', $data);
            $this->isOtpGenerated = true;
        }
        $this->timer = 30;

my code On the blade file:
<div x-data="{ timer: @entangle('timer') }">
    <p>OTP: {{ $otp }}</p>
    <p x-show="timer > 0">Resend OTP in <span x-text="timer"></span> seconds</p>
    <button wire:click="resendOTP" x-bind:disabled="timer > 0">Resend OTP</button>
</div>


You should specify better which problem you are having
